# Ctrl, Alt, and Super behave like Left Shift and I fixed it in a strange way

Tags: linux, arch-linux, keyboard, wireshark

I use Arch Linux. I have Qumo Axe keyboard which as it turned out works only on Windows. On Linux, the bottom row keys (Ctrl, Alt, Super) behave like Left Shift, I tried to install drivers which I found on Google but without any success. After that, I decided to capture USB input in Wireshark (with usbmon), then something strange happened - when I started Wireshark, my keyboard started to work as it should work.

Does anyone know why it happened? It makes no sense for me

Comment: Now I have to start Wireshark on every reboot to make my keyboard work as it should